# How do i limit the number of "chips" that are displayed in multiple ui-select?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-select

I'm working on an AngularJS project and I currently need to limit the number of displayed "chips" in a `ui-select multiple`.

By this, I don't mean limit the number of total possible selects the user can make. I want to limit only the ones that are visible. For example, the user may be able to select 5 options but only 3 will be visible.

Sample code is below:

```
<ui-select multiple require-multiple required name="production_units" max-labels="3" ng-model="device.device_production_units" ng-disabled="disabled" append-to-body="true">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="{{system.devices | translate}}">{{$item.name || $item.external_id}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="option in (lookups.device_production_units | filter:$select.search) track by option.id">{{option.name}}</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In your repeat you can use this filter [limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Comment: The thing is that in ui-select there is no explicit repeat